# UDP Packets not Sending Possibly Due to Client Not Found?

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

I have an application that is very simple. It sends out UDP packets to a client somewhere else on the network.

The host computer is 192.168.11.66 (Windows 10), the client device is 192.168.11.65 (proprietary device).

The host pc cannot see the client device, however I know that it is on and listening to traffic. When I send UDP packets from the host, I use Wireshark and I do not see the packets being sent out. Instead I see messages from ARP trying to locate the client. I assume because ARP is unsuccessful, the host cancels the sending of the packets.

If I change the destination address of the packets to a broadcast address, all of the packets get sent and I see everything on Wireshark. I need to be able to specify the IP address of the client and have Windows send the packets regardless of whether or not it thinks the client device is on the network or not. The client device looks for UDP traffic specifically addressed to itself and the client device has no way of making itself visible on the network.

Does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: Do you see the same ARP no-sending-packets behavior if you `connect()` your sending socket to the device's IP and then send packets using `send()` rather than `sendto()`?  I've never heard of a UDP socket refusing to send packets to an IP before.  UDP is connectionless.  Typically, if you try to send a packet to a non-existent destination, it will go out and then you will get back an ICMP error packet from the network (which Windows will usually not deliver to an app unless the UDP socket is `connect()`ed). At least, that has been my experience with UDP.

Comment: Apparently this ARP behavior is [documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc940021(v=technet.10)) (see the "ARP and UDP Messages" section). It says to use [`SendARP()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-sendarp) to create an ARP record on the local machine, but that doc says it only happens if the ARP request is successful.Try using [`CreateIpNetEntry()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-createipnetentry) instead to create your own ARP record manually.

Comment: You need the layer-2 address of a destination in order to build layer-2 frames to the destination. ARP resolves the layer-3 address to the layer-2 address in order to get the layer-2 address for the layer-2 frames. Broadcast works because it uses the layer-2 broadcast address, which goes to all hosts on the layer-2 network. Your host must know the destination layer-2 address before it can build a layer-2 frame to the destination.

Comment: Remy - Thank you. I was able to use your comment and add a manual entry into the ARP. I was able to use NETSH and add neighbors. Both of which worked. Thank you for your input. I do not know how to mark your comments as an answer.

Comment: Is this an ethernet-specific application? If so, does the sender know the receiver's ethernet hardware address?

Comment: @Deltris comments can't be marked as accepted, only answers can be. I didn't post an answer at the time because I wasn't sure what I commented would work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Remy:  instead to create your own ARP record manually. – Remy Lebeau

I did not realize that I could create manual entries in the ARP. I need to read more about ARP. Adding a manual entry solved my issue. I found that you could do it using ASP -s, or add neighbor using NETSH .

Thanks!